# Open GL ES rendering display only a white image of a 3D model

Tags: ios, opengl-es, openframeworks

I have a problem with openFrameworks. Some 3D models are displayed correctly but basic 3D models like a chair with no texture is painted in white with no shadows. Drawing only the wireframe of the model is ok. Here is a [picture of the result](http://www.pcv-soft.com/Images/chair.jpg) I am getting:

[image]

The chair model comes from Sketchup warehouse and has been converted to dae. The model is displayed correctly within Xcode and the Finder.

I am not an expert in openGL and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the application/example that you are using does not handle vertex colors, or does not handle them in a way compatible to your exported models.

If indeed models without a texture have issues and with texture everything is ok your easy solution will be to bake textures for the models that have none in SketchUp.

If you want to fix the code instead you first need to know if you are using OpenGL ES 1.1 or 2.0? (should be printed to terminal on application start - default is 1.1, enabling 2.0 is typically done using the call `ofSetCurrentRenderer(ofGLProgrammableRenderer::TYPE);`)

In OpenGL ES 2.0 positioning of vertices and coloring/texturing is all done in shaders, to fix those you need to find them. They are usually placed in the bin/data dir of your openFrameworks project and are compiled on the video card, no need to compile them yourself. All white for a model could indicate that you are not normalizing values where it is needed. (e.g. the expected values might be between 0 and 1, but your values could be between 0 and 255).

In OpenGL ES 1.1 there are no shaders - coloring using vertex colors should work out of the box, but normalizing still applies.

Another option is that 'white' is simply your default color for models and no vertex color data is being used at all - either because it's not in the DAE file or because it's not being handled correctly.